# Message.framework error

Tags: iphone

I try to add Message.framework to my project frameworks directory.
After that I compile my project,(no additional codes) it reported that

Command/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.plateform/Developer/usr/gg-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Welcome any comment

Thanks
interdev

Comment: it said that framework no found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is not the Message.framework problem.
You may put some error code.